# Import Packages from different local folder without sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path, package

I have a directory structure like:

```
proj/
 |- src/
   |- org/
     |- example/
       |- dir/
         |- foo.py
         |- ...
 |- src2/
   |- org/
     |- example/
       |- dir/
         |- bar.py
         |- ...
```

My question is: How to import `foo` into `bar` without using `sys.path` and, if possible, avoid writing a `__init__.py` file in every subdirectory of `src`? Note that the actual .py files are located in the `dir` folders only if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`from src.org.example.dir import foo`

Comment: This raises an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` .